# Quill Editor - Focus

Tags: html, quill

Whenever I create another instance of the editor (in my case, through an onkeypress event), I lose focus on the editor I was typing on when the new editor is created. How can I prevent all editors from losing focus on any event?

Answer (score 11):

Quill has a method called `focus()` for this.

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  theme: 'snow'
});

// This will focus the instance of quill editor
quill.focus()
```

Comment: If I update the following jsfiddle to include quill.focus() I don't get focus...

const quill = new Quill("#quill-editor", {
 theme: 'snow'
})
let text ="How do I focus on Quill editor?"
quill.insertText(0, text);
quill.focus()

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8d1gh7rn/5/

Does it perhaps have to do with the modal? Any help appreciated!

Comment: @11teenth This might be because when opening the model bootstrap focuses the modal losing the focus that was on quill. Trigger `quill.focus()` after the animation is done. https://jsfiddle.net/qeyn1b42/

Comment: via using bootstrap modal events

`$('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
            setTimeout(() => {
                quill.focus()
            }, 600)
        })`

Answer (score 6):

```
setTimeout(() => { 
  quill.focus();
})
```

It will work

Comment: Please explain why your solution works with an additional source supporting your claim.

Comment: It tooks some time to render the view meanwhile we are calling the focus method.. So the editor isn't focused.